# Bigcommerce API Add Images

Tags: bigcommerce

Using the legacy API in bigcommerce, trying to add a product image without success.  I have done this before but it seems to not work now.

The API documentation says that there is a function to 'create a product image', however it says that the field 'product_id' is read only and any request will be rejected if it is included.  If that is true and not a typo, how are you supposed to create a product image against a product?

Answer (score 0):

Don't add product ID to the parameters, add it to the url.  So if you want to add images to product 12345, make a post to

```
'/products/12345/images'
```

of the image data

```
{ 'sort_order': 1, 'image_file': 'http://blah.jpg' }
```